# Delete all files and folders but exclude a subfolder

Tags: powershell

I have a folder where I need to delete all files and folders except a small list of files and folders.

I can already exclude a list of files, but don't see a way to exclude a folder and its contents.

Here is the folder structure:

```
|-C:\temp
 \-C:\temp\somefile.txt
 \-C:\temp\someotherfile.txt
| |-C:\temp\foldertodelete
   \-C:\temp\foldertodelete\file1.txt
| |-C:\temp\foldertokeep
|  \-C:\temp\foldertokeep\file2.txt
```

I want to keep somefile.txt and the folder foldertokeep and its content.

This is what I have right now:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path  'C:\temp' -Recurse -exclude somefile.txt | Remove-Item -force -recurse
```

This really does not delete somefile.txt. Is there a way to exclude folder foldertokeep and its content from the delete list?

Comment: What am i missing here? This seems to work for me `Get-ChildItem -Path  'C:\temp' -Recurse -exclude somefile.txt, foldertokeep | Remove-Item -force -recurse`

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Select everything excluding what needs to be keep and pipe that to a delete command.

Say you have those folders

```
C:.
├───delme1
│   │   delme.txt
│   │
│   └───delmetoo
├───delme2
├───keepme1
│       keepmetoo.txt
│
└───keepme2
```

To delete everything but preserve the keepme1 and keepme2 folders.

```
Get-ChildItem -Exclude keepme1,keepme2 | Remove-Item -Recurse -Force
```

Other solutions are fine but I found this easy to understand and to remember.

Comment: I like this solution, you only need one recurse though: `Get-ChildItem -Exclude folder1,folder2 | Remove-Item -Recurse -Force
`

Comment: So true @AxelWass, even better solution then XD

Answer (score 68):

```
Get-ChildItem -Path  'C:\temp' -Recurse -exclude somefile.txt |
Select -ExpandProperty FullName |
Where {$_ -notlike 'C:\temp\foldertokeep*'} |
sort length -Descending |
Remove-Item -force
```

The -recurse switch does not work properly on Remove-Item (it will try to delete folders before all the child items in the folder have been deleted).  Sorting the fullnames in descending order by length insures than no folder is deleted before all the child items in the folder have been deleted.

Comment: Complicated and brilliant and typical of the roughness of Powershell.  I hope it keeps evolving.  Thanks.

Comment: I had to add an additional [-Recurse] param to the last line to get the script to proceed without prompting.

Comment: What is the `sort length -Descending` doing?

Comment: That sorts the file and directory fullnames by the length of the fullname string, in descending order.  That insures that it doesn't attempt to delete a directory until all the child items of the directory have been deleted.

Answer (score 33):

In PowerShell 3.0 and **below**, you can try simply doing this:

```
Remove-Item -recurse c:\temp\* -exclude somefile.txt,foldertokeep
```

Unless there's some parameter I'm missing, this seems to be doing the trick...

Edit: see comments below, the behavior of Remove-Item has changed after PS3, this solution doesn't seem applicable anymore.

Comment: I was doing this in PowerShell 3.0 and it was working great. However, I just noticed that the behavior changed in PowerShell 4.0. For example, say you have directories "a" and "b" in the same parent directory and file "c.txt" under directory "a". If you run "rm .\\* -Recurse -Exclude a" from the parent directory. In PS 4, c.txt will be deleted. In PS 3 it won't. I'm wondering if this is a bug in PS 4 as it doesn't make sense IMHO.

Comment: @JonMiller Same problem here. Migrated from PS2 to PS4 noticed some important directories were wiped from one of our systems. Good thing for backups. :)

Comment: Great info in the comments.  So maybe this is not a safe technique to use given different possible behaviors depending on PowerShell version?

Comment: lol. it honoured the exclude folder, but alas not its contents

Comment: Just had a look at it again. It looks even worse than what @JonMiller mentions. From what I'm experimenting, -exclude is only applied on the root directory when using -recurse. That definitely looks like a bug... Edit: nevermind, it's weirder than that.

Answer (score 8):

I used the below and just removed -Recurse from the 1st line and it leaves all file and sub folders under the exclude folder list.

```
   Get-ChildItem -Path "PATH_GOES_HERE" -Exclude "Folder1", "Folder2", "READ ME.txt" | foreach ($_) {
       "CLEANING :" + $_.fullname
       Remove-Item $_.fullname -Force -Recurse
       "CLEANED... :" + $_.fullname
   }
```

Answer (score 7):

Yes I know this is an old thread. I couldn't get any of the answers above to work in Powershell 5, so here is what I figured out:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $dir -Exclude 'name_to_ignore' |
ForEach-Object {Remove-Item $_ -Recurse }
```

This moves the -Recurse to Remove-Item instead of where the items are found.

Answer (score 6):

According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.management/remove-item#example-4-delete-files-in-subfolders-recursively) `Remove-Item` has a known issue with the `-exclude` param. Use this variant instead.

```
Get-ChildItem * -exclude folderToExclude | Remove-Item
```

Comment: Note: `<folderToExclude>` should only be the `folderToExclude`'s name without trailing `\*` else it will be leaving empty directories at 1st level (only, not beyond)

Answer (score 4):

This would also help someone...

Adding a variable for PATH_GOES_HERE that is empty or isn't defined prior can cause a recursive deletion in the user directory (or C:\windows\system32 if the script is ran as admin). I found this out the hard way and had to re-install windows.

Try it yourself! (below will only output the file directories into a test.txt)

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $dir2 -Recurse -Exclude "Folder1 ", FileName.txt | foreach ($_) {
$_.fullname >> C:\temp\test.txt
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I ran into this and found a one line command that works for me. It will delete all the folders and files on the directory in question, while retaining anything on the "excluded" list. It also is silent so it won't return an error if some files are read-only or in-use.

```
@powershell Remove-item C:\Random\Directory\* -exclude "MySpecialFolder", "MySecondSpecialFolder" -force -erroraction 'silentlycontinue'
```

Answer (score 2):

I used this, that works perfectly for me

```
Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\Temp\*' -Recurse | Where-Object {($_.FullName -notlike "*windirstat*") -and ($_.FullName -notlike "C:\Temp\GetFolderSizePortable*")} | Remove-Item -Recurse
```

Answer (score 1):

If your paths include regex special characters then you need to use the -LiteralPath option which does not allow piping. The correct solution in that case looks like this:

```
    Remove-Item -force -LiteralPath(    
    Get-ChildItem -Path  'C:\temp' -Recurse -exclude somefile.txt |
    Select-Object -ExpandProperty FullName |
    Where-Object { $_ -notlike 'C:\temp\foldertokeep*' } |
    Sort-Object length -Descending 
)
```

Answer (score 0):

This would also help someone...

```
Get-ChildItem -Path PATH_GOES_HERE -Recurse -Exclude "Folder1 ", "Folder2", FileName.txt | foreach ($_) {
    "CLEANING :" + $_.fullname
    Remove-Item $_.fullname -Force -Recurse
    "CLEANED... :" + $_.fullname
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I want get contribution for this idea

- delete all folder and files include hidden folder

$get-childitem -Path D:\path\folder\to\delete* -Force |select-object -Expandproperty Fullname |remove-item -recurse -Confirm:$false -Force

- delete all folder and file include hidden folder but retain exclude folder

$get-childitem -Path  D:\path\folder\to\delete* -Exclude nameexludefolder -Force | select-object -Expandproperty Fullname | remove-item -Force

$get-childitem -Path D:\path\folder\to\delete\ -Exclude nameexludefolder -Force | select-object -Expandproperty Fullname | remove-item -Force

first line remain folders,
2nd line remove remain folder

Answer (score 0):

In case you want preserve svn repository like git, the main folder is hidden by default and you may not want to delete it with other files and folders, cd into the folder in Powershell and simply do:

```
Get-ChildItem | Remove-Item -Recurse
```

The hidden folder and its unhidden contents are preserved by default. It solves that issue for me.