# Powershell remove-item exclude switch is not excluding files provided with full path

Tags: powershell

Powershell `Remove-Item` exclude switch is not excluding files provided with full path.

Code:

```
Remove-Item "$DeploymentPath\*" -Exclude "$DeploymentPath\Web.config" -recurse
```

Result: `web.config` is deleted.

please help me with this. I have to provide full path as I have another `web.config` file in other folder, which I should delete.

Comment: Since you are using `-recurse`, this might be the solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14775672/delete-all-files-and-folders-but-exclude-a-directory

Comment: Exclude works with files and _not_ folders/paths. You need to use a different logic like the one in the question tagged by Ocaso