# How to exclude folder with a specific name from deletion from the entire folder tree in Powershell scripting?

Tags: powershell, scripting, automation

I have powershell scripts running on a remote server that delete files older than 30 days stored on shared drives using automated tasks. We have excluded this folder with a specific name from deletion which is usually found in the root directory of the shared drives. However in one of the shared drives, this folder is found one level below the root level, and there are seven such subfolders. I want to exclude this folder with the *specific name* from deletion in all these subfolders with a single script. Is there a way to do this? Here is the script I am currently using-

`Get-Item -Path $Delete_Global_Test -Force -exclude $Keep_this_folder,$Keep_this_folder2|Get-ChildItem -Recurse|Where-Object {!$_.PSIsContainer -and $_.CreationTime -lt $regional_limit}|Remove-Item -Recurse -Force -Verbose`

Answer (score 0):

adding -Exclude "notthisfolder" would be my solution

Comment: as you can see, I have already used 
"-exclude $Keep_this_folder,$Keep_this_folder2"

this does not save the folder with the specified name from deletion beyond the root directory

Comment: add the -exclude to the "Get-ChildItem - Recurse -Exclude $a,$b" instead of adding it at the Get-Item

that works for me

Comment: ok, another try. 
Get-Item -Path Delete_Global_Test  | Get-ChildItem  -Exclude $Keep_this_folder,$Keep_this_folder2 -Recurse | Where-Object{$_ -notmatch "\\$Keep_this_folder\\" -and $_ -notmatch "\\$Keep_this_folder2\\" }

Comment: basically, even to my understanding -exclude should work after Get-ChildItem command, but somehow it is failing, not sure why

Comment: well. i tried to create some folders like
c:\Test\
with subfoldes A, B and C
each of them with subfolders &files
and tried to exclude the Folders A and B with all subfolders.
works for me. up to now i've no clue why it's not working for you.
but i will keep on eye on this question, as i'm really curious about the solution and why it didn't work for you

Comment: no actually, my problem is, the folders I have to exclude from deletion are not in the root, they are one level below the root, i.e., these folders that I want remain untouched are in the the 7 subfolders present in the root folder, i.e., I need these 7 folders with the same name excluded from deletion which are in the 7 subfolders of the root directory.

Comment: perhaps you should provide a screenshot with the folder structure and then using that explain which would be the ones to keep and the ones to remove.

Comment: as already users Kiran and Nate R mentioned, please provide more details to your folder structure.
maybe similar like done in this posting
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14775672/delete-all-files-and-folders-but-exclude-a-directory

Comment: Let's say X is root (a mapped drive) and Y1-7 are subfolders and Z is the name of the folder I want to completely exclude from deletion ($Keep_this_folder)(that is, even its subfolders should be excluded). so structure is like this-

X:\Y1\Z, 
X:\Y2\Z, 
X:\Y3\Z, 
X:\Y4\Z, 
X:\Y5\Z, 
X:\Y6\Z, 
X:\Y7\Z

Answer (score 0):

If you know the directory, and the directory name never changes, why don't you just create a secondary path variable that drills down into that directory and run the script again?

So if this works for you (your code), why not just create a second path variable (e.g. $Delete_Global_Test2) which drills down to the directory that's one deeper and rerun the same command on a new line, but using your second path variable?

Your script would work like this:

```
Get-Item -Path $Delete_Global_Test -Force -exclude $Keep_this_folder,$Keep_this_folder2|Get-ChildItem -Recurse|Where-Object {!$_.PSIsContainer -and $_.CreationTime -lt $regional_limit}|Remove-Item -Recurse -Force -Verbose
#Now run again but in a second root path
Get-Item -Path $Delete_Global_Test2 -Force -exclude $Keep_this_folder,$Keep_this_folder2|Get-ChildItem -Recurse|Where-Object {!$_.PSIsContainer -and $_.CreationTime -lt $regional_limit}|Remove-Item -Recurse -Force -Verbose
```

And all you'd have to add is the declaration for $Delete_Global_Test2, which would be the same as $Delete_Global_Test but with the additional subdirectory appended to the original.

Would that work for your purposes?

Comment: Indeed it has worked and that was the first solution in my mind. But for that I have to give seven different paths and seven scripts for deletion inside these seven subdirectories. What I was looking for was a way to exclude this folder which has the same name inside all the seven different subfolders just using some command for the purpose of excluding items (folders, to be precise) with specific name over the entire folder tree.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your organization for your directory.  Can you please give an example of your structure?  The "seven such subfolders" is the part I think is catching me.  Also, that is all one script; are you trying to say you want it all as one LINE?