# power shell remove-item recurse sub directory 3 level down

Tags: powershell, recursion

I can't figure out a way to recursively remove all folders except a sub-sub directory in each folder called "broadcast"

```
Dir
->subdir1
-->main
-->broadcast
->subdir2
-->main
-->broadcast
->test
```

I want to keep all the subdir#\broadcast folders and test folder.
Problem with this code below is that this removes the subdir1 and subdir2 in few recursion below, which removes the sub-sub directory

```
Get-ChildItem -Path  $copy_file -Recurse |
Select -ExpandProperty FullName |
Where {$_ -notlike '*broadcast\*'  -and $_ -notlike '*testing*'} |
sort length -Descending |
Remove-Item -force
```

I can't use -force /a because this list I get when I sort includes the subdir1 and subdir2...

```
It does prompt me "This item has children..."
[Y] Yes [A] Yes to all... [L] No to all
```

I do want it to automatically select L

any suggestions? Thank you in advance... I did look through but couldn't find an exact solution I am looking for.

Comment: You should have 2 loops. First just gets the immediate children (not recurse) of  `$copy_file`. From your question you don't want to remove any of these. Then for each of those folder run a second loop for their children. Filter from their. Using `-Directory` with `Get-ChildItem` should help as well.

Comment: Good idea Matt, only problem is I have X amount of subdir :(

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Delete all files and folders but exclude a directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14775672/delete-all-files-and-folders-but-exclude-a-directory)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will exclude the 'broadcast' folder (you can replace with your) and then you can pass the object into the remove-item

```
Get-ChildItem -Path D:\ -Recurse -Exclude @('broadcast') -Directory | ForEach-    Object($_){
Write-Host $_.FullName
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I forgot to mention it is for ps 2.0 ... 4.0 stuff -directory or foreach doesn't exist :(

Answer (score 0):

What this will do is navigate the top path `$copyfile` and pull all child directories. Not recursive just the immediate children. For each of those children we will filter out all folders with the name broadcast. Of those that remain, delete them

```
Get-ChildItem -Path  $copy_file -Directory | ForEach-Object{
    Get-ChildItem -Directory -Path $_.FullName | Where-Object{$_.Name -ne "broadcast"} | Remove-Item -Force -WhatIf
}
```

You might need to add `-Recurse` to `Remove-Item` and I left `-WhatIf` there so you could test.

Comment: I thought it was best practice to filter LEFT of the pipeline as it's more efficient, for example using `Get-ChildItem` and the `Exclude` param.

Comment: @user4317867 Very true. I am trying to show a basic example given the directory structure. What you are suggesting is a good idea. Exlcude does not always work as intended when you are not using recurse so this is a precaution that and the structure does not look that involved.

Comment: Wouldn't above try to remove subdir1 and subdir2? This way forces confirm menu, which I can't make it select "L" (no for all)

Comment: @TaehoonAKim Did you actually try it? No. It won't try and remove those folders. -WhatIf is there so that you see what you need to do. You can also set `-Confirm:$false` to remove the prompts. There could also be an issue with this because I do not see where your directories start compared to your example. Glad you got your answer.