# PowerShell Delete everything else except one file in root and one in sub folder

Tags: powershell, build-automation

I need to delete all files and folders except one file in root folder and one other file in sub folder. Furthermore file names are passed as an argument to the script as comma sep1rated string like 'file1.txt,Subfolder\file2.txt'.

I was trying to do something like this,

```
$Path = "C:\\Delete\\"
$Argument= "file1.txt,Subfolder\\file2.txt"
$ExcludedFiles = [string]::Join(',', $Argument);
$files = [System.IO.Directory]::GetFiles($Path, "*", "AllDirectories")
    
foreach($file in $files) { 
    $clearedFile = $file.replace($Path, '').Trim('\\');
                
    if($ExcludedFiles -contains $clearedFile){
        continue;
    } 
            
    Remove-Item $file
}
```

By doing this all the folders remain and all the files get deleted.
Can any one please suggest that how should I try to do this since I am having difficulty in doing this.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The easiest way to get it done is using the `-Exclude` paramater in `get-childitem`.

Here are the examples to Exclude a file:

```
Get-ChildItem C:\Path -Exclude SampleFileToExclude.txt| Remove-Item -Force
```

Exclude files with a specific extension using wildcard:

```
Get-ChildItem C:\Path -Exclude *.zip | Remove-Item -Force
```

Get all the files recursively and exclude the same:

```
Get-ChildItem C:\Path -Recurse -Exclude *.zip | Remove-Item -Force
```

Exclude list of items as per your wish in the same command:

```
Get-ChildItem C:\Path -Recurse -Exclude *.zip, *.docx | Remove-Item -Force
```

You can even use with array and where condition:

```
$exclude_ext = @(".zip", ".docx")
$path = "C:\yourfolder"
Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Recurse | Where-Object { $exclude_ext -notcontains $_.Extension }
```

And then you can remove using `Remove-Item`

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for your help but you see my root folder can have multiple txt files i need to delete them except one particular file, so deleting files using extension is not feasible although i tried using  
Get-ChildItem C:\Path -Exclude SampleFileToExclude.txt| Remove-Item -Force
but it still deletes everything furthermore how can i secure the second file which is inside the sub folder since i have to run this command once and also i am getting the exclude file names in argument.

Comment: @HaiyanJamali: what is the name of the file in specific and tell me the root folder path in specific .

Comment: There are two approaches: First try to use only get-childitem with Exclude parameter and mentioning the specific file names. This will list down the files except the files you have kept in exclude. If it is still showing the excluded ones, then some issue in the names or space issue or some other issue. Further if it lists down, then go for the pipeline object for removal

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/a/14776054/2715716 to see why *this* is better than `Remove-Item -Recurse` if you're wondering why not just use that.