# File Directory traversal

Tags: powershell

there is situation where in temp folder there are multiple folders such as Parent folder - abc234, child folder -rty12 and under rty12 there are multiple files and i want to retain folder rty12 by using powershell :
I am using below script but this is not working as per requirement:

```
$DateToDelete = 0
$StartFolder = "C:\temp"
$folderstoRetain = "C:\temp\abc234\rty12"

dir $StartFolder -Recurse -Exclude $folderstoRetain -Force -ea 0 | ? 
{!$_.PsIsContainer -and $_.LastWriteTime -lt (Get- 
Date).AddDays(-$DateToDelete)} | del -Force
```

Comment: do you want to keep the _folder_ only, or do you want to exclude the content of that folder?

Comment: "this is not working" ... *how?* The code you posted is broken (b/c it's wrapped incorrectly). Please create a [mcve], test-run that code, then [edit] your question and copy/past *that* code into your question. Also include all errors *that* code produces.

Comment: How are you checking that a folder to delete isn't a parent/sub folder of one to retain? You code as it stands would retain "C:\temp\abc234\rty12" but delete all subfolders of that folder.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Delete all files and folders but exclude a directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14775672/delete-all-files-and-folders-but-exclude-a-directory)