# PowerShell Remove-Item exclude folder files

Tags: powershell

I have a simple script which is used to delete files from a folder. The script accepts two parameters:

1. The path of the folder to delete from
2. A list of items to be excluded from deletion

This is the script I have:

```
Param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
    [string]$pathDeleteFrom,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
    [string[]]$excludeFiles
)

Remove-Item -path $pathDeleteFrom -exclude $excludeFiles -Recurse
```

I'm testing the script in a folder with the following structure:

[image]

Example (running the script for path "C:/test/files/*"):

- If `"*.txt"` is excluded, only the `.json` files are removed.
- If I want to delete all files except the folder and it's contents I tried excluding `"folder"` and `"folder/*"`, however it doesn't seem to work.

What I'm failing to understand is, whether there's a way for me to exclude the `"folder"` and it's contents using wildcards.

I know that this is probably a simple question but I have tried searching online but failed to find an example similar to the scenario that I have.

Comment: my understanding is that the `-Exclude` & `-Include` parameters in ps5.1 **_only work on the actual file name_** - the `.Name` part. if you want to operate on dir names, you will need to do your own filtering. ///// i have been told that ps6+ allows those parameters to work on the `.FullName` property, but i have not tested that.

Comment: Ahh right understood... it was driving me crazy, I thought that it should be simple enough to filter out a folder and its contents.. I guess I was wrong. Thanks for your comment I will try to go about it in a different way.. maybe add another parameter containing folder names and then handle the rest myself.

Comment: After a bit more research I think I've finally found a solution. https://stackoverflow.com/a/14776054/2312637. From what I'm understanding this script uses the FullName property to filter files that includes the folder names.

Comment: that is what i meant by "filter it yourself". [*grin*] the `Where-Object` cmdlet will do that job ...

Comment: Yep that should do it :) thanks for the info.. pointed me in the right direction.

Comment: you are most welcome ... glad to help a tad! [*grin*]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do what you're trying to accomplish... just fill in the blank and modify the condition statements to what you need.

```
$items = Get-ChildItem -Path "Directory Path" -Recurse

foreach($item in $items)
{
    if($item.name -like "*.TXT" -or $item.name -like "*.Json")
    {
        #CODE HERE
    }
    elseif(($item.GetType()).Name-eq "DirectoryInfo" -and $item.name -eq "Directory Name")
    {
        #CODE HERE
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, this is similar to what I ended up doing.. thanks a lot