# Delete Folders and Files but exclude a subfolder

Tags: powershell

I have a folder structure like this:

```
C:\somewhere
├───Test
│   ├───DoNotDelete
│   │   └───Test 4
│   └───Test 3
└───Test 2
    ├───Test 5
    └───Test 6
        └───Test 7
```

All of these folders contain files. As you can see there is one folder called `DoNotDelete`. I would like to delete everything, except the `DoNotDelete` Folder and everything below and also keep the parent folders of my `DoNotDelete` Folder. That means, in the end it should like this:

```
C:\somewhere
└───Test
    └───DoNotDelete
        └───Test 4
```

I tried some suggestions of this question: [Delete all files and folders but exclude a subfolder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14775672/delete-all-files-and-folders-but-exclude-a-subfolder)

- `gci C:\somewhere -recurse | ? {$_.FullName -notlike '*DoNotDelete*'} | % { remove-item $_.Fullname -force }` <-- This simply deleted everything
- `gci C:\somewhere -recurse -exclude DoNotDelete` <-- this did not exclude the folder I wanted to exclude
- `gci C:\somewhere -recurse | ? {$_.DirectoryName -notmatch '.*DoNotDelete.*'}` <-- this also listed my `DoNotDelete` folder. I also tried `BaseName` instead of `DirectoryName` but it still didn't work.
- `gci C:\somewhere -recurse | Remove-Item -Exclude DoNotDelete -Recurse` This also does not seem to work. it deletes all files everywhere, but keeps all folders

One challenge is that the folder I want to exclude could be anywhere in the foilder structure. right after the top folder, or 5 levels deeper or anything in between.

Does someone have a suggestion?

Comment: Can you please clarify the intention? Are you wanting to empty the tree, leaving the entire content of `DoNotDelete` in tact? Or are you wanting to, empty every file from `DoNotDelete` and its subdirectories, but leave those subdirectories in tact? Also your current code should use `gci`'s `-Directory` option, otherwise it will leave any files named `DoNotDelete` in place too.

Comment: grab all the dirs in the tree, use `-notmatch` on the `.FullName` to exclude the unwanted items.

Comment: @Compo I would like to delete all the files and folders, except everything inside the `DoNotDelete`. So basically if there are files inside the `Test` Folder, they should get deleted. If there are Files in the `DoNotDelete` folder, they should not get deleted

Comment: @Lee_Dailey mmh, that does not seem to work Lee. if you mean it like this: `gci C:\somewhere -recurse | ? {$_.FullName -notmatch '.*DoNotDelete.*'}`, because this would return the parent dir of DoNotDelete, and if i delete that, DoNotDelete is also deleted

Comment: … and if there are directories and subdirectories inside the `Test4` directory?

Comment: @Compo nope, since it's below a `DoNotDelete` Directory, files and folders in test 4 should not be touched

Comment: So to clarify, you want to remove, all directories, _(with their content)_, which do not have a `DoNotDelete` descendant, and also all content from the remaining tree which does not have a `DoNotDelete` ancestor.

Comment: @Compo correct!

Comment: @Compo - i left out a step. [*blush*] the `DirInfo` object you get back from `G-CI` will have a `.Parent` property that you can use to navigate up the dir tree and remove those from your "kill these" list.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it (for multiple folders to exclude if you like) like below:

```
# create a regex of the files and/or folders to exclude
$Exclude = 'DoNotDelete'  # this can be an array of foldernames to exclude or a single item
# each item will be Regex Escaped and joined together with the OR symbol '|'
$notThese = ($Exclude | ForEach-Object { [Regex]::Escape($_) }) -join '|'

(Get-ChildItem -Path 'D:\Test' -Recurse).FullName |
    Where-Object { $_ -notmatch $notThese } |
    Sort-Object Length -Descending |
    Remove-Item -Force
```

The -Recurse switch does not work properly on Remove-Item (it will try to delete folders before all the child items in the folder have been deleted).
Sorting the fullnames in descending order by length ensures than no folder is deleted before all the child items in the folder have been deleted.