# Deleting folders with Powershell recursively issue

Tags: powershell

I need to delete some subfolders under a folder 'ToDelete'. I am using this to do that: (both should do the same deletion). my problem is that there is other folder called 'Do_Not_Copy' under ToDelete folder that contain also a folder called 'Tools' that should not be deleted. how I can protect this 'Tools' subfolder? -Exclude doesn't work.
My workaround for now is to use Rename-Item for the Tools folder

```
$DestinationFolder = "\\google\server\ToDelete"

Remove-Item -Path $DestinationFolder\  -Include "Tools", "Support", "Installer", "GUI", "Filer", "Documentation" -Recurse -Exclude "Do_not_copy\SI\Tools" -Force 
Get-ChildItem $DestinationFolder\ -Include "Tools", "Support", "Installer", "GUI", "Filer", "Documentation" -Recurse -Force | ForEach-Object { Remove-Item -Path $_.FullName -Recurse -Force }
```

Comment: you can refer this question:
....
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14775672/delete-all-files-and-folders-but-exclude-a-subfolder

Comment: Not good for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `-Recurse` switch does not work properly on Remove-Item (it will try to delete folders before all the subfolders in the folder have been deleted).
Sorting the fullnames in descending order by length ensures than no folder is deleted before all the child items in the folder have been deleted.

Try

```
$rootFolder = '\\google\server\ToDelete'
# create a regex of the folders to exclude
$Exclude = 'Do_not_copy\SI\Tools'  # this can be an array of items to exclude or a single item
# each item will be Regex Escaped and joined together with the OR symbol '|'
$notThese = ($Exclude | ForEach-Object { [Regex]::Escape($_) }) -join '|'
# the array of folder names (not full paths) to delete
$justThese = 'Tools', 'Support', 'Installer', 'GUI', 'Filer', 'Documentation'

(Get-ChildItem -Path $rootFolder -Directory -Recurse -Include $justThese).FullName |
    Where-Object { $_ -notmatch $notThese } |
    Sort-Object Length -Descending |
    Remove-Item -Recurse -Confirm:$false -Force -WhatIf
```

As usual, I have added the `-WhatIf` safety switch, so no folders will be deleted and in the console you can see what *would* happen.
When satisfied the correct folders will be removed, comment out or remove that `-WhatIf` switch and run again

---

Since the code above uses regex to determine if a fullname matches (or in this case not) the string contained in `$notThese`, we need to make sure all characters that have special meaning for regex in that string are correctly escaped with a backslash. See the table below.
To do that, the code loops over the string(s) in the string or array in `$Exclude` and escapes these using `[Regex]::Escape($_)`.
After escaping, the strings are combined with the regex `OR` symbol `|` using `-join '|'`

**Special Characters in Regex**

| Char | Description | Meaning |
| --- | --- | --- |
| \ | Backslash | Used to escape a special character |
| ^ | Caret | Beginning of a string |
| $ | Dollar sign | End of a string |
| . | Period or dot | Matches any single character |
| | | Vertical bar or pipe symbol | Matches previous OR next character/group |
| ? | Question mark | Match zero or one of the previous |
| * | Asterisk or star | Match zero, one or more of the previous |
| + | Plus sign | Match one or more of the previous |
| ( ) | Opening and closing parenthesis | Group characters |
| [ ] | Opening and closing square bracket | Matches a range of characters |
| { } | Opening and closing curly brace | Matches a specified number of occurrences of the previous |

Comment: Thank you champ, I got a confirmation popup. any way to a void this?

Comment: @Bandit I have added `-Confirm:$false`. Does that help?

Comment: unfortunately no

Comment: @Bandit Then where and when does it trigger a confirmation? Can you show us exactly what it says ?

Comment: The item at $rootFolder\Installer has children and the Recurse parameter was not specified

Comment: Thank you @Theo for your effort. I am gonna using your solution once it will work without popups. would be more easier to rename for now the folder as I wrote as workaround?

Comment: Remove-Item -Recurse -Force -WhatIf should help I think no?

Comment: Remove-Item -Recurse -Force  did the job. make sense?

Comment: @Bandit `-Recurse` is ok (i forgot that but added it now), the `-WhatIf` is just a safety measure so that nothing actually gets deleted. It does not stop confirmation messages

Comment: I know what is -WhatIf. when I added the -Recurse I not getting the message. make sense?

Comment: Now the -Confirm:$false is not needed

Comment: @Bandit So that message was from the **content** of the folder to delete and yes, `-Recurse` was needed.

Comment: Hi @Theo
Can you please explain what does { [Regex]::Escape($_) }) -join '|'
How does it work?

Comment: @Bandit Please see my edit