Script Issue: "Expressions are only allowed as the first element of a pipeline"
I have a very long script that runs on a local machine and works as expected.
I am working on moving it to a pipeline. I encountered those errors (when I removed them all worked as expected).
I will start with the code and afterward the errors:
The code is deleting some folders and except others and it's not located at the beginning of the script
 write-host "Deleting an old content from $DestinationFolder"
            Write-Log -logfile $loglocation -Message "Deleting an old content from $DestinationFolder"
           
            # create a regex of the folders to exclude
            $Exclude = 'Do_not_copy\SI\Tools', 'Do_not_copy\AutomaticTesterTests\Tests\Editing\GUI'  # this can be an array of items to exclude or a single item
            # each item will be Regex Escaped and joined together with the OR symbol '|'
            $notThese = ($Exclude | ForEach-Object { [Regex]::Escape($_) }) -join '|'
            # the array of folder names (not full paths) to delete
            $justThese = 'Tools', 'Support', 'Management Console', 'Installer', 'GUI', 'Filer', 'Documentation'

            (Get-ChildItem -Path $DestinationFolder -Directory -Recurse -Include $justThese -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue).FullName |
            Where-Object { $_ -notmatch $notThese } |
            Sort-Object Length -Descending |
            Remove-Item -Recurse -Force 
            write-host "Extract $Latestpackage to $DestinationFolder"
            Write-Log -logfile $loglocation -Message "Extract $Latestpackage to $DestinationFolder"
            Try {
                $zip = [System.IO.Compression.ZipFile]::ExtractToDirectory((Convert-Path $Latestpackage.PSPath), $DestinationFolder)
            }
            Catch {
                Write-Host "Unable to extract $Latestpackage to $DestinationFolder"
                exit
            } 

The errors:
2024-10-22T09:52:05.8787706Z E:\Agt1\Default\06\_w\r25\a\AgileQA\AutomaticScript\GetPatches.ps1 : At 
2024-10-22T09:52:05.8788687Z E:\Agt1\Default\06\_w\r25\a\AgileQA\AutomaticScript\PatchVerification.ps1:4823 char:88
2024-10-22T09:52:05.8789650Z + ... item will be Regex Escaped and joined together with the OR symbol '|'
2024-10-22T09:52:05.8790219Z +                                                                         ~
2024-10-22T09:52:05.8790759Z Expressions are only allowed as the first element of a pipeline.
2024-10-22T09:52:05.8791570Z At E:\Agt1\Default\06\_w\r25\a\AgileQA\AutomaticScript\PatchVerification.ps1:4824 char:85
2024-10-22T09:52:05.8792820Z + ... These = ($Exclude | ForEach-Object { [Regex]::Escape($_) }) -join '|'
2024-10-22T09:52:05.8793423Z +                                                                         ~
2024-10-22T09:52:05.8795106Z Expressions are only allowed as the first element of a pipeline.
2024-10-22T09:52:05.8795915Z At E:\Agt1\Default\06\_w\r25\a\AgileQA\AutomaticScript\PatchVerification.ps1:4826 char:27
2024-10-22T09:52:05.8796893Z +             $justThese = 'Tools', 'Support', 'Management Console', 'I ...
2024-10-22T09:52:05.8797421Z +                           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
2024-10-22T09:52:05.8798303Z Unexpected token 'Tools', 'Support', 'Management' in expression or statement.


Try replacing '|' with '`|'.  The backtick will escape the pipe character.

The code you're showing wouldn't produce the syntax errors you're showing; you'll need to provide more information.

My code came from here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75030298/deleting-folders-with-powershell-recursively-issue

That doesn't help. Just like your extended version of the linked code doesn't produce the errors, neither would the linked code.

I have 6000 rows..

replacing '|' with '`|' doesn't help

Regardless to the error  '|' can be replaced with "|"

@mklement0 how you explain that everything works when this part is disabled?

The code works syntactically in isolation, so if commenting it out makes a difference, the implication is that it was incorrectly embedded in a larger script, causing syntax errors. Try providing a [mcve]. In the process of crafting one, you may find that you'll discover the problem yourself.

Got it :) I find the issue, this was the problem Donâ€™t
I don't know how

Save your script file as UTF-8 with BOM.
